# To get around standard Windows scrollbars 32bit limitation

Tags: c++, windows, scrollbar

Im facing a situation where int fields of standard `SCROLLINFO` struct for `GetScrollInfo` / `SetScrollInfo` API is no longer enough. It's a scrolling of a big data, >4GB.

Googling on subject didn't give any feasible answer.
One solution, of course, would be to implement my own control with similar functionality, but it's not a trivial task.

So the question is, how to get around this limitation, not reimplementing the wheel?
May be someone did something similar already?

Comment: You don't scroll line-by-line. You scroll in blocks. No user is going to scroll line by line through 4GB+ of information.

Comment: Do you really have more than 4000 million _lines_ in your listbox or whatever?

Comment: I'd say that the limitation is inflicted by the height of the scrollbar in pixels. So typical scroll is limited as ~1000 positions. Scrollbar is simply not the right kind of control when you want to navigate over large amount of data. You may consider implementing multi-level scrollbar for example

Comment: @KenWhite It's now scrolling in blocks, of course. Unfortunately it's not the remedy, or block size should be very big. In case of big data (dozens of GB) 32bit is not enough.

Comment: As I said, no user in their right mind is going to want to scroll through 4GB of data. You're also butting up against reasonable memory limits (if you've not surpassed them already).

Comment: @KenWhite I, for sure, don't understand your logic. There is a clear limit of standard scrollbar of 32bit. But you insisting on user's willings. How these facts do correspond is beyond me.

Comment: I understand the limit very well. My point is that no user with any sort of brain is going to want to scroll through multiple gigs of data. You're solving a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. But good luck.